# WebBrowser url issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've an html page index.html in my windows application folder. Now I want to set it as a url of webbrowser in form1. How can I do it? Is there any syntax like `server.mappath()` in web applications in windows?

Example:

```
Uri repuri = new Uri("index.html");
webBrowser1.Url = repuri;
```

How can I map it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

Returns the full path of your exe-file, including the filename itself. You could use that to build a path to your HMTL-file.